How to make HTTP connection to an IPv6 address in Ruby?
I am trying to perform a POST call to a REST service hosted on IPv6.
require 'ipaddr'
require 'json'
require 'net/http'
require 'base64'
require 'uri'


request_uri="https://[2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000]/path/to/service"
url = URI(request_uri)

http = Net::HTTP.start(url.host, url.port)

But I see this error
Traceback (most recent call last):
       13: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `<main>'
       12: from /usr/bin/irb:23:in `load'
       11: from /usr/share/gems/gems/irb-1.2.6/exe/irb:11:in `<top (required)>'
       10: from (irb):13
        9: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:606:in `start'
        8: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:938:in `start'
        7: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:943:in `do_start'
        6: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:958:in `connect'
        5: from /usr/share/ruby/timeout.rb:105:in `timeout'
        4: from /usr/share/ruby/timeout.rb:95:in `block in timeout'
        3: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:960:in `block in connect'
        2: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:960:in `open'
        1: from /usr/share/ruby/net/http.rb:960:in `initialize'
SocketError (Failed to open TCP connection to [2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000]:443 (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known))


If I use hostname instead of this IPv6, then the call goes through.
How do I make this work?

Does https://[2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000]/path/to/service work when you type it in your browser?

The error says getaddrinfo: Name or service not known) meaning it's trying to resolve the address, so it did not get it's a IPv6 address.
What ruby/uri version are used ?

How @Fravadona said, try to request this URL in another context (browser, cURL, Postman). Other thing: your port section have two ":" - (::1000) - it's right?

Yes, if I do a curl on https://[2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000]/path/to/service, it works. 2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000 is a valid IPv6 address. And since its a valid IPv6 address, I am not sure why it is trying to resolve and fail. Ruby version: ruby 2.7.8p225 (2023-03-30 revision 1f4d455848) [x86_64-linux]

irb(main):001:0> require 'ipaddr'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> ip = IPAddr.new("2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000")
=> #<IPAddr: IPv6:2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:0100:0000:0000:1000/ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff:ffff>
irb(main):003:0> ip.ipv6?
=> true

What about removing the brackets? Net::HTTP.start("2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000", 443)

@Fravadona: yes that worked! So it looks like url.host sets it to [2002:cafe:cafe:cafe:100::1000], while Net::HTTP.start expects it without the [].
Thanks for your help!
